# How do I get the public DNS for an Amazon Workspace (virtual desktop)?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, reverse-proxy, virtual-machines

Running nginx reverse proxy on an Amazon Workspace (virtual desktop).  How can I get a public DNS or a stable public ip address (like an elastic IP?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually assign Elastic IPs to a WorkSpace if it is in a public subnet. But instead of attaching them directly to instances as you might have done with EC2 instances, you need to attach them to the WorkSpace's public subnet Network Interface. The [Amazon WorkSpaces documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/amazon-workspaces-vpc.html#assign-eip) explains how this is done:

> **To assign an Elastic IP address to a WorkSpace manually**
>
> 1. Open the Amazon WorkSpaces console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/.
> 2. In the navigation pane, choose **WorkSpaces**.
> 3. Expand the row for the WorkSpace and note the value of **WorkSpace IP**. This is the primary private IP address of WorkSpace.
> 4. Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/.
> 5. In the navigation pane, choose **Elastic IPs**. If you do not have an available Elastic IP address, choose **Allocate new address** and
>      follow the directions.
> 6. In the navigation pane, choose **Network Interfaces**.
> 7. Select the network interface for your WorkSpace. Note that the value of **VPC ID** matches the ID of your WorkSpaces VPC and the
>      value of **Primary private IPv4 IP** matches the primary private IP
>      address of the WorkSpace that you noted earlier.
> 8. Choose **Actions**, **Associate Address**.
> 9. On the **Associate Elastic IP Address** page, choose an Elastic IP address from **Address** and then choose **Associate Address**.